# Sending iMessage from server like SMS

Tags: imessage

Recently I receive an iMessage and when I click it, my iPhone automatically open the app store.

It's an advertisement obviously, but I don't know how I receive that iMessage. So can someone tell me if Apple provides open API for sending iMessage?

And if it's not, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a link you clicked? If so you were probably sent to a website which in turn sent an HTTP redirect to an `itunes://` URL:

https://www.apple.com/itunes/link/

Comment: Maybe it's a method. But the question is that why I can receive an advertisement by iMessage?